# Laravel Auth::attempt no funciona correctamente

Tags: php, laravel

Acabo de empezar con Laravel y poco a poco voy sacando cosas en claro, el problema que se me presenta es que al introducir los datos en mi formulario login, y compararlos con mi bbdd la autentificación de estas credenciales siempre sale falso, y no entiendo porque, os dejo unos fragmentos de código:

LoginController:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class LoginController extends Controller
{


    public function iniciarSesion(Request $request)
    {
        $credenciales = array(
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->contraseña
        );
        if (Auth::attempt($credenciales)) {
            // Authentication passed...;
            return redirect()->route('core.get.dashboard');
        }
        //La autenticación no ha funcionado
        
    }

    public function cerrarSesion()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->intended('inicio');
    }
    //
}
```

Usuario Factory:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Usuario;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UsuarioFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Usuario::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'Julia',
            'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('contrasena'), // contraseña
            'updated_at' => now(),
            'created_at' => now(),
        ];
    }
}
```

BBDD:

[image]

Formulario Login:

```
<form class="mt-8" action="{{ route('admin.post.iniciar-sesion') }}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <div class="rounded-md shadow-sm">
            <div class="mt-4">
                <label for="email" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Correo electrónico</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" type="email" required placeholder="Correo electrónico" class="appearance rounded relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900  focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5">
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4">
                <div class="flex justify-between">
                    <label for="contraseña" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Contraseña</label>
                    <a href="{{ route('admin.get.he-olvidado-mi-contraseña') }}"
                        class="font-medium text-xs text-brand-600 hover:text-brand-500 focus:outline-none focus:underline transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Contraseña olvidada?
                    </a>
                </div>
                <input id="contraseña" name="contraseña" value="{{ old('password') }}" type="text" required placeholder="******" class="appearance-none rounded relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5">
            </div>
        </div>

            <button type="submit"class="group relative w-full mt-6 flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm leading-5 font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-brand-600 hover:bg-brand-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-brand-700 focus:shadow-outline-brand active:bg-brand-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                Iniciar sesión
            </button>


    </form>
```

Según estos datos el usuario debería ser "admin@admin.com" y la pass seria "contrasena". Pues al introducir estos datos en el login me da falso.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Nos muestras tu formulario de login?

Comment: Si disculpa, lo acabo de añadir ahora.